# Heap corruption occurs when a function or sub-routine is returned during encryption functions

Tags: c++, encryption, memory-leaks, heap-corruption

I'm trying to encrypt an AES key with an RSA public_key and print the encrypted bytes out on the console. I'm using Windows Cryptographic APIs to encrypt the key and also using Microsoft's documented way of getting size of buffer that is required for encrypted bytes like in the code provided below:

The issue i am facing is that every time when my program is executed and lockKey function is called, on every return it give error of heap corruption even though all code in the lockKey function has been executed successfully. I've debugged the code, but couldn't find the reason because every time the exception is thrown on function return (ending parenthesis).

Complete code is provided below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
using namespace std;

void lockKey(std::string, HCRYPTKEY, HCRYPTPROV);
void handleError(const char*);
std::string byteToHex(BYTE*, DWORD);

void handleError(const char* message)
{
    cerr << message << " error code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    exit(1);
}

std::string byteToHex(BYTE* inputBytes, DWORD inputSize)
{
    std::string outputString;
    DWORD hexSize = 0;
    if (!CryptBinaryToStringA(inputBytes, inputSize, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, NULL, &hexSize))
    {
        // handle error
        handleError("Failed to get size of encrypted bytes key");
        return NULL;
    }

    outputString.resize(hexSize, '\0');
    if (!CryptBinaryToStringA(inputBytes, inputSize, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, &outputString[0], &hexSize))
    {
        // handle error
        handleError("Failed to convert encrypted bytes key to hexSize");
        return NULL;
    }
    //outputString.resize(hexSize - 1); // remove null terminator
    return outputString;
}

void lockKey(std::string publickey, HCRYPTKEY hKey, HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv)
{
    //Import RSA public key
    std::vector<BYTE> publicKeyBytes;
    DWORD publicKeySize = 0;
    if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(publickey.c_str(), publickey.length(), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &publicKeySize, NULL, NULL)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error getting binary size");
    }
    publicKeyBytes.resize(publicKeySize);
    if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(publickey.c_str(), publickey.length(), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, publicKeyBytes.data(), &publicKeySize, NULL, NULL)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error converting to binary");
    }

    HCRYPTKEY phKey = NULL;
    if (!CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, publicKeyBytes.data(), publicKeyBytes.size(), 0, 0, &phKey)) {
        CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error importing key");
    }

    //Export AES key for encryption
    //Determine the size of the buffer needed for the exported key
    DWORD dwBufSizeAES = 0;
    if (!CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB, NULL, NULL, &dwBufSizeAES))
    {
        CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error determining key buffer size");
    }

    // Allocate a buffer for the exported key
    //BYTE* pbAesKey = new BYTE[dwBufSizeAES];
    //memset(pbAesKey, 0, dwBufSizeAES);
    std::vector<BYTE> pbAesKey(dwBufSizeAES, 0);

    // Export the key to the buffer
    if (!CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB, NULL, pbAesKey.data(), &dwBufSizeAES))
    {
        CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error exporting key");
    }

    //Encrypt AES key with RSA public key
    //Determine the size of the buffer needed for the encrypted key
    DWORD dwBufSize = 0;
    if (!CryptEncrypt(phKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwBufSize, 0))
    {
        CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error determining encrypted buffer size");
    }

    //PBYTE pbEncryptedKey = (PBYTE)malloc(dwBufSize);
    std::vector<BYTE> pbEncryptedKey(dwBufSize, 0);

    // Encrypt the AES key with RSA-OAEP padding
    DWORD cbAesKey = 0;
    if (!CryptEncrypt(phKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pbAesKey.data(), &cbAesKey, dwBufSize))
    {
        CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Error encrypting AES key");
    }

    memcpy(pbEncryptedKey.data(), pbAesKey.data(), dwBufSize);   

    // Now pbEncryptedKey contains the encrypted AES key
    std::string hexEncryptedKey = byteToHex(pbEncryptedKey.data(), dwBufSize);
    cout << "Encrypted AES Key Bytes: \n" << hexEncryptedKey << endl;
    CryptDestroyKey(phKey);

} //error always on this line of code.

int main()
{
    DWORD blockSize;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;

    // Import the RSA public key as in the previous example.
    std::string publickey = "valid public key"; //removed

    // Generate aes key
    hCryptProv;
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Failed to acquire cryptographic context");
    }
    hKey;
    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Failed to generate key");
    }
    // Get the block size for the algorithm
    blockSize;
    DWORD dwDataLen = sizeof(DWORD);
    if (!CryptGetKeyParam(hKey, KP_BLOCKLEN, (BYTE*)&blockSize, &dwDataLen, 0)) {
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        handleError("Failed to get block size");
    }
        
    lockKey(publickey, hKey, hCryptProv);
    
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    return 0;

}
```

The screenshots for errors are as follows:

[image: Exception in visual studio]

If continued then it give heap corruption error:

[image: Heap corruption]

I was using memory management functions at first like memset, malloc, free, delete etc. But because of heap errors. I've shifted my buffers to vectors which i understand are much better to use avoiding memory corruption. However, my error is still not solved. I've debugged the program and check available values and buffer of each variable as well. Everything is at it should. I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::string` can't be constructed from `nullptr`, you pass a `char*` null pointer, that is an invalid C-string. Use `return {}`.

Comment: When you see the exception in Visual Studio, you also can see the stack call, "Show Call Stack". Please [edit] and show it in the post as a pre-formatted text.

Comment: Also, if you really and truly mean that `return NULL;` means "This didn't work", then return a `std::optional<std::string>` or even a `std::pair<std::string, bool>` where the `second` of the pair denotes whether there was a failure or not.

Comment: The way to track this down is to start eliminating code. Change your `lockKey` function so that it only makes the first function call (to `CryptStringToBinaryA`). Do you get heap corruption then? If not then add in the next function call. Keep going until the heap corruption returns, Then at least you know what is causing the corruption.

Comment: You could press "Copy Details" and post them here as a text instead of pictures.

Comment: Just an fyi the call to `GetLastError()` is far too late to be any use.  It needs to be immediately after the error has been detected.  Almost any library function call or OS call can reset the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question to ChatGPT-4 and got the accurate answer. It looks like the issue was the way i was handling the encrypted key's buffer. When I call CryptEncrypt, the `pbAesKey` buffer is being overwritten with the encrypted data. However, I have allocated `pbEncryptedKey` to store the encrypted key separately. Instead of copying the encrypted data from `pbAesKey` to `pbEncryptedKey`, I should have been encrypting the data directly into `pbEncryptedKey`.

So replacing the code

```
if (!CryptEncrypt(phKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pbAesKey.data(), &cbAesKey, dwBufSize)){
    CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    handleError("Error encrypting AES key");
}
memcpy(pbEncryptedKey.data(), pbAesKey.data(), dwBufSize);
```

with

```
memcpy(pbEncryptedKey.data(), pbAesKey.data(), dwBufSizeAES);
if (!CryptEncrypt(phKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pbEncryptedKey.data(), &dwBufSizeAES, dwBufSize)){
    CryptDestroyKey(phKey);
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    handleError("Error encrypting AES key");
}
```

resolved the issue.

This way, I am first copying the AES key into `pbEncryptedKey`, and then using `pbEncryptedKey` as the buffer for the encrypted data. After that, I can safely use `pbEncryptedKey.data()` to convert the encrypted key to a hex string without any heap corruption issues.

Comment: Microsoft API written for C rather than C++. So are the documentations. You must master resource management in C++, before using those docs, or you'll end up with lots of repetitive code and risk of dropping something, leading to catastrophy. Microsoft never provides API for std C++. So extra Caution is needed dealing with those APi.